# algorithm for randomized routing between two tiles on an 8x8 grid

Tags: routes, grid, tiles

I'm looking to find a way to generate a randomized path between two tiles on an 8x8 grid. Most of the algorithms I've looked at are concerned with finding the shortest path.

For example:

If I was trying to find a path between points (1,1) and (8,8), most algorithms would give a solution like: [image: algorithm]

I'm looking for one like:
[image: algorithm]

^ That's just an example. The path between S and F could be any random walk.

Thanks in advance!